# How to add a id for many stock to be insert to database sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a dynamic add form field function to add many stock in 1 order to database.

However I was unable to insert the same order_id for the order that contain many stock. I need to use the order_id to print back the order detail

```
ordertable
--------------------------------------------------------
| order_id | order_item_id | item_name | item_quantity |
--------------------------------------------------------

stocktable
-----------------------------------------------------
| item_id | item_name | item_descript | item_quantity |
-----------------------------------------------------

 <?php  
 require_once('../config.php');

 $number = count($_POST["item_name"]); 
 $item_name=$_POST['item_name'];
 $item_quantity=$_POST['item_quantity'];
 $order_id = uniqid();

 if($number > 0)  
 {  
  for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
  {  
       if($item_name[$i]!="" && $item_quantity[$i]!="")  
       {  
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ordertable(order_id,item_name,item_quantity) 
             VALUES('$order_id','$item_name[$i]','$item_quantity[$i]')";  
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
       }  
  }  

  }   
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: so you are getting any error?

Comment: no error, just only can insert 1 row to database instead of insert many row and the order_id always be 59

Comment: You had trying to store multiple rows with single query and your order id is unique thats the issue,
cos all rows getting same order id

Comment: have to taken order id unique in db?

Comment: so you want that each time new id will generate and added to table and also multiple record will add not one time?

Comment: that's what i want to keep the order_id same for 1 order that contain many different item name

Comment: Actually your problem is still ununderstandable.

Comment: check your order table is order id is unique or primary or any other?

Comment: my order_id is primary with AI

Comment: It is simply a case of incorrect database design. Fix the design, and the functionality you want will be easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema needs some changes. `stocktable` contains a list of stock items. `ordertable` *should* contain a list of orders, and you are missing a `orderdetailtable` which contains each of the stock items for a given order.

The problem is that in your schema, you have the order table, with the primary key of `order_id` and you are expecting to put all the order line-items in with the same `order_id`... This isn't going to work.

Create a new table to hold the order line-items, and have the order table with the order-specific information, such as customer, date, etc. The order detail table can be seen as a link table between orders and stock items.

```
ordertable
------------------------------
| order_id | order_date | ...
------------------------------

orderdetailtable
----------------------------------------------------------
| order_detail_id | order_id | stock_id | order_quantity | 
----------------------------------------------------------

stocktable
--------------------------------------------------------
| stock_id | item_name | item_descript | item_quantity |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**
The code above will need to change as well, to cater for the new database structure.

```
...
if($number > 0)  
{  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ordertable(order_id, ...) VALUES('$order_id', ...";  
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  

    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
    {   
        $order_detail_id = uniqid();
        if($item_name[$i]!="" && $item_quantity[$i]!="")  
        {  
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orderdetailtable(order_detail_id,order_id,stock_id,item_quantity) 
               VALUES('$order_detail_id','$order_id','$item_id[$i]','$item_quantity[$i]')";  
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    }  
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but order_id using the uniqid() still keep 59 for every new order, it won't change. Have any method to handle the every new order_id?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Every new order should have exactly one record in the ordertable, with exactly one unique order_id. Each item on the order will have a record in the orderdetailtable, which points back to the single record in the ordertable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `uniqid()`, which is not appropriate for a table id for several reasons, but the relevant one to your problem is that it will return *not* an integer but an *alphanumeric* string like this:

```
59f9a69367e7f
```

When you try to use that value as the `order_id` MySQL try to convert it to number stopping at the first non numeric character, so you always get "59".

The simplest  methods for fixing this is define the `order_id` column with [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html), in this way MySQL will generate automatically an unique identity for new rows. If you need to get that id for later use you can get it using [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Note that when inserting in tables with auto incremented id you skip the id column from the column list, in your case you will use:

```
INSERT INTO ordertable (item_name,item_quantity)
```

As a final note, **you code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)**, you should use [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: thanks, i change to the order_id to varchar and able to get the unique id. I have use mysqli_prepare() in login session and i thought SQL injection would be useless in data insert page

Comment: SQL injection is relevant in *all* locations in which you use data from the user to query/modify the DB, not only SELECT operations, see the third example [of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (and that are only basic examples, you can perform more complex operations with SQL injection).